# Display the first name, birthdate and age for all customers whose older than 50

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select first_name, birth_date, DATEDIFF(hour,birth_date,sysdate)/8766 AS Age
from ACDB_CUSTOMERS 
where (sysdate - age)>50;`
```

> ORA-00904: "AGE": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Whence is the divisor value of `8766` ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined `DATEDIFF()` function within Oracle, but [`ADD_MONTHS()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603) and [`MONTHS_BETWEEN()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669) might be used such as

```
SELECT first_name,
       birth_date,
       TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(sysdate),birth_date)/12) AS Age
  FROM acdb_customers
 WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate),-12*50)<= birth_date
```

or replace the `WHERE` condition with `TRUNC(sysdate) - INTERVAL '50' year <= birth_date`

Comment: Or a bit simpler `where sysdate - interval '50' year <= birth_date`

Answer (score 0):

"age" isn't in scope; nest the query without the filter and then use the filter outside the nested query:

```
select *
from (
    <your query>
)
where
    (sysdate - age) > 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use a column alias defined in the `select` in the corresponding `where`.  However, Oracle supports lateral joins, so you can move the definition to the `from` clause so it works:

```
select c.first_name, c.birth_date, x.Age
from ACDB_CUSTOMERS c cross join lateral
     (select DATEDIFF(hour, birth_date, sysdate)/ 8766  as age
      from dual
     ) x
where x.age > 50;
```

Your definition of age seems rather arcane -- and Oracle doesn't support `datediff()` anyway.  And your `where` clause just doesn't make sense.

I would suggest instead using months.  So a fixed up query would look more like this:

```
select c.first_name, c.birth_date, x.Age
from ACDB_CUSTOMERS c cross join lateral
     (select months_between(sysdate, birth_date) / 12 as age
      from dual
     ) x
where x.age > 50;
```